moving photos by Google Takeout to iCloud datetime bug
I encountered strange bug with moving photos from Google Photos to iCloud. I used official way to move it https://takeout.google.com/takeout/transfer/custom/photos.
Everything is almost fine, photos begin copying after few minutes but almost all of them have incorrect datetime (-10h). Screens bellow, because is really hard to explain :D I'm in -2/-1 timezone, so it's not related to this.
Same photo on Google Photos, iPhone gallery and iCloud on Windows Chrome browser.

